# Download while uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

How to use PHP or any other language to read an uploading-file to allow download of the uploading-file while it is uploading?

Example sites that does this are:

1. http://www.filesovermiles.com/
2. http://host03.pipebytes.com/

Comment: In HTTP there is always one request: A client sends request to a server, the server responds to the client: That's *always* up- (client to server) and down-load (server to client). Please be more specific what you're asking for.

Comment: I agree with you but the problem is how to read the uploading file byte by byte and push to a download stream to another client on "real time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867

In the array the file name is included as temp_filename - so you can pass that to your other program, which can read from the file and stream it live. The array also includes a file size so that program can make sure not to try to read beyond the end of the file.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know APC could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in PHP because PHP takes care of receiving the download and only hands over control when it has the complete file. When writing CGI programs or Java servlets you read the upload from the socket so you are in control while receiving the file and you can administer if it is still uploading and how much has been received so another process could read this data and start sending what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

One of the site's you've given as an example is just downloading a file from an URL or from the client computer, stores it temporarily and assigns a code to that file to make it identifiable.

*After* uploading, any other user who has the code can then download that file again.

This is more a question how you operate a server system then writing the code.

You can download files to the local system by making use of `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

If you want to stream file-data from the server to the browser, you can make use of [`readfile` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).